how to find out bolt sizes
I'm looking for a resource to look up bolt sizes for my Ford Focus. Like the one pictured that I found on a parts website, but ideally with real sizes on it.
Is there a document I can search for or any resource that would have this information? the Haynes Manual has torque specs, as does the factory workshop manual, but no more information.


https://ford.7zap.com/en/car/43/no/0/1660/16076/70289/#HB3

YES! That's the site I have been looking for. top man
